# Using a Wacom Tablet and pen for QGIS, can I pause my free-hand polygon before I am finished, and then continue?

Tags: qgis, polygon, digitizing, pan, tablet

Is there a way to pause the free-hand tool in QGIS so that I can lift the pen off of the screen, and then continue my polygon again when I am ready?
I have learned how to pan while free-hand drawing but I'd like to be able to take my pen off the screen, maybe have it create a node point without closing the polygon, and then being able to go back and continue from that node to complete my polygon?
Does such a thing exist?

Comment: just to clarify, where is the tool "free-hand tool"?

Comment: It is a plug in that you can add, and then use when you want to edit the shape file, it is found in the toolbar with the add and edit feature options